# Write API response from R to a CSV file

Tags: r, json, csv

I'm using an API to retrieve data from one of our systems. Here is the R code suggested in Postman:

```r
res <- VERB("GET", url = "https://us-central1-iattended-a2e10.cloudfunctions.net/periods?orgId&apiKey")

cat(content(res, 'text'))
```

Here is a sample of the response:

```
[{"periodId":"5adf8aaa806bf0e2d643","periodName":"LU Chapel Spring 2024","startTime":{"_seconds":1704693600,"_nanoseconds":0},"endTime":{"_seconds":1714798740,"_nanoseconds":0},"numberRequired":20,"eventTypeId":"xkeaJ23SZsSPLgw1X4Xs","eventType":"LU Chapels","createdOn":{"_seconds":1704823664,"_nanoseconds":994000000}},{"periodId":"hpkTq1CtDcFdVnojPgIe","periodName":"LU Chapel Fall 2023","startTime":{"_seconds":1692594000,"_nanoseconds":0},"endTime":{"_seconds":1702792740,"_nanoseconds":0},"numberRequired":20,"eventTypeId":"xkeaJ23SZsSPLgw1X4Xs","eventType":"LU Chapels","createdOn":{"_seconds":1692804844,"_nanoseconds":930000000}}]
```

How do I turn and write this response into a CSV file, using R?

```
cat(content(res, 'text'), file = "chapel.csv")
```

When I add the above code to the last line, I do get a CSV file, but the data are not organized into rows and columns. When I open in Excel, all the data run along the first row to infinity.

I appreciate any help to point me in the "write" direction of parsing the response into a properly structured output file. Thank you!

Comment: A "CSV file" is just a text file that may or may not have actual comma-separated values in it. This is clearly not that. It looks to be [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), use `dat <- `[`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html)`::fromJSON(content(res,'text'))` and you'll get a frame. From there, use `write.csv(dat, "chapel.csv", row.names=FALSE)` if you need it in a file.

Comment: Thank you r2evans, this is exactly what I was looking for! Your suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: Ok, so another question...

Comment: res <- VERB("GET", url = "https://us-central1-iattended-a2e10.cloudfunctions.net/periodProgress?orgId=&apiKey=&periodId=")
dat <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res,'text'))
write.csv(dat, "chapelv2.csv", row.names=FALSE)

Comment: When i run the code above, I get the following error: Error in dimnames(X) <- list(dn[[1L]], unlist(collabs[nc > 0], use.names = FALSE)) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent  What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Here is a sample row of the JSON output: [{"userId":"jQ7PrQ0QSpXDVLUeN6PNiugdl392","userEmail":"abc@abc.edu","userName":"Abc","rearrangedName":"Abc, Abc","creditsEarned":13,"creditsRequired":20,"directCreditsEarned":0,"directCreditsRequired":null,"percentageCompleted":65,"periodId":"5adf8aaa806bf0e2d643","periodName":"LU Chapel Spring 2024","eventType":"LU Chapels","eventTypeId":"xkeaJ23SZsSPLgw1X4Xs","recordUpdatedAt":{"_seconds":1709228717,"_nanoseconds":181000000},"studentId":"L987654321","isActive":true,"isGhost":false,"inactiveSubscription":false,"tags":[]}

Comment: Well, for me that request returns a HTTP 403, meaning that I don't have permissions to hit that API. That error looks like it's coming from `write.csv`, so you need to look at the return value from `fromJSON(..)` to see what it is. It is entirely possibly (I'd even wager _"likely"_) that it is not a simple tabular frame. It sounds like you need to understand the structure of your data a bit better, not everything can be manipulated as a `data.frame` in R.

Comment: That's an incomplete (or _invalid_) message since it doesn't close out properly, but it's _mostly_ a frame but one column `recordUpdatedAt` is actually a nested `data.frame`. The `write.csv` and related functions require perfectly tabular, so it errs quickly. Take a look at `str(jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res,'text')))` to see what I mean. Try adding `flatten=T`, as in `jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res,'text'), flatten=TRUE)`, though you still have `$tags` which will cause it to fail still.

Comment: If you know that you don't need the `$tags` field and you're good with flattening the other field, then you can do `content(res, 'text') |> jsonlite::fromJSON(flatten=TRUE) |> transform(tags=NULL) |> write.csv("some/path/file.csv", row.names=FALSE)` or such.

Comment: Thanks, r2evans, you pointed me in the right direction! I ended up using the subset() function to remove the columns I didn't need,  recordUpdatedAt and tags. Now it runs to CSV perfectly.